# Using json_decode to retrieve ajax-sent javascript array for email

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I'm trying to email the contents of a JS array by encoding using JSON.stringify and then decoding in the PHP which should then be sent via email. I get a success alert that the data is sent to the PHP okay, but the email doesn't come through. Can anybody spot anything glaringly obvious I'm missing/got wrong, please?

Array has been populated via **.push** function and I can output that fine in the HTML, so I know it's populated.

Using ajax to encode my data string:

```
dataString = myArray; 

var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataString);

 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "script.php",
    data: {data : jsonString}, 
    cache: false,

    success: function(){
       alert("Success");
    }
});
```

Then in the PHP:

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

$to = "my@email.com";
$header = "Content-Type: text/html\r\nReply-To";
$subject = "This is my Subject Line";

$body = 
    @"
    <strong>The data is:</strong> $data
    ";


    if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) {
        die("true");    
        } else {
            die("There was an error sending the email.");   
        }
?>
```

The email doesn't come through at all, and I don't get any error messages at all. Can anybody help, please? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't convert $data array to string directly.

You have to use print_r($data, true) to insert contents of the array into a string

Answer (score 0):

Has you got a mailserver in the PHP machine?

`mail()` returns true if the mail is accepted to delivery, but this doesn't mean it's sent at all.

Comment: Yes, the server should be set up correctly as I've sent emails via PHP before!

Comment: And where does your program end? At `die("true")` or at the second `die()`?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you don't have a mail server.

What you can do quickly is, go to this link,

http://www.toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/

Download the tool. follow the steps to run it.

Then change your code to this to see things that you can do,

```
<?php
$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']));

$to = "abc@gmail.com";
$header = "Content-Type: text/html\r\nReply-To";
$subject = "This is my Subject Line";

$body = 
@"
<strong>The data is:</strong> 
".print_r($data, true) ;


if(mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) {
    die("true");    
    } else {
        die("There was an error sending the email.");   
    }
?>
```

I think you will get the value but how you will use it that's your choice.

Cheers.

Comment: I think you haven't configured it properly. You should get the mail locally. You can check it in your local store(configured folder).